# Bash find filename and set to variable

Tags: bash

I want to find the name of a file in a folder on my server and set it to a variable to use it later.  The problem is when I run my backup script the file name changes each time to compensate for the date.  So I cannot just hard code the file name and path.

For example I know where the file will be - /var/backups/"unknownfilename.sql"

```
 backuppath="/var/backups/"
```

How can I set $backupfile to the file in $backuppath?

After researching I can only find where people echo out the filenames, they never end up storing them to a variable.

Comment: You can assign the output of any command to a variable, with `var=$(command)`.

Comment: ...but if there's a directory which will have only one file in it (as the question seems to imply), using `find` is silly.

Comment: Woops your right my mistake.

Comment: The spaces are wrong too. `backuppath = "/var/backups/"` tries to run a command named `backuppath` with its first command-line argument being `=` and its second command-line argument being `/var/backups/`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For bash (`#!/bin/bash`):

```
backuppath=/var/backups
sqlfiles=( "$backuppath"/*.sql )
[[ -e $sqlfiles ]] || { echo "Matched no files" >&2; exit 1; }
```

If you want to refer to the first match:

```
echo "The first match found was: $sqlfiles"
```

If you want to refer to all array contents:

```
echo "Found the following files:"
printf '- %q\n' "${sqlfiles[@]}"
```

---

For POSIX sh (`#!/bin/sh`) instead:

```
backuppath=/var/backups

# wrap in a function to avoid overwriting the global $1, $2, etc.
find_files() {
  set -- "$backuppath"/*.sql
  [ -e "$1" ] || { echo "Matched no files" >&2; exit 1; }
  [ "$#" -gt 1 ] && echo "WARNING: Matched $# files; only taking first" >&2
  sqlfile=$1
}
find_files
```

---

Points of note:

- The expansion itself (`"$backuppath"`) should be inside quotes; the glob expression (`*.sql`) should not.
- Testing whether the first element found exists (`[[ -e $sqlfiles ]]` in bash, `[ -e "$1" ]` in the POSIX sh version) protects against default behavior when no matches exist, which will use the glob expression itself (`/var/backups/*.sql`) as a result; when tested for existence, this won't be present unless a file exists with literally that name (which is to say, a name containing an asterisk).
- The first form uses two behaviors present in bash (the shell you tagged your question for), but not `/bin/sh`: Arrays, and the extended (`[[ ]]`) test operator. If you were to use the standard test command, it would be `[ -e "$sqlfiles" ]` instead; if you were to operate in a shell without arrays, you might wrap this logic in a function and use `set -- "$backuppath"/*.sql` to put results into the array-like object `"$@"`, after which you could refer to the first match as `"$1"`, or the full set of matches as `"$@"`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  
    sqlfiles=( "$backuppath"/*.sql )

Comment: Actually how could you make it so it finds the last file in the folder, just in case there were multiple files?

Comment: "last" sorted by name, or meaning "latest" by date? The former would be `"${sqlfiles[${#sqlfiles[@]} - 1]}"`; the latter is the subject of BashFAQ #3: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003